# Why are my Authentication Emails not working? I get an "AuthenticationError"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, heroku, devise

Whenever I reset my password or attempt to get an email confirmation I see this sort of error page:

**`Net::SMTPAuthenticationError in Devise::PasswordsController#create`**

It looks like the email is sending as I see this in my Rails Server logs, however at the bottom of it you can see I get some sort of 500 error.

This only happens when I'm sending email authentication from development (I've included my development.rb file below).  Seems to be working fine on Heroku.

*I've included my email logins on a separate .env file so you don't see it here and I've changed my email address in these logs for privacy.*

Any help is appreciated!

**Rails Server Logs:**

```
(0.9ms)  commit transaction
  Rendered devise/mailer/confirmation_instructions.html.erb (1.1ms)

Sent mail to xx@xx.com (958.0ms)
Date: Wed, 23 Apr 2014 10:51:46 -0700
From: xx@xx.com
Reply-To: xx@xx.com
To: xx@xx.com
Message-ID: <5357fdb28f720_199810d2ab033cb@unknown20c9d07bac9b.mail>
Subject: Confirmation instructions
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<p>Welcome xx@xx.com!</p>

<p>You can confirm your account email through the link below:</p>

<p><a href="http://localhost:3000/users/confirmation?confirmation_token=ukG1PXbXyXP5LpjG1Eaa">Confirm my account</a></p>

Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 964ms

Net::SMTPAuthenticationError (530-5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at
):
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/smtp.rb:948:in `check_response'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/smtp.rb:917:in `getok'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/smtp.rb:832:in `mailfrom'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/smtp.rb:659:in `send_message'
  mail (2.5.4) lib/mail/network/delivery_methods/smtp.rb:113:in `block in deliver!'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/smtp.rb:520:in `start'
  mail (2.5.4) lib/mail/network/delivery_methods/smtp.rb:112:in `deliver!'
  mail (2.5.4) lib/mail/message.rb:2129:in `do_delivery'
  mail (2.5.4) lib/mail/message.rb:232:in `block in deliver'
  actionmailer (4.0.0) lib/action_mailer/base.rb:456:in `block in deliver_mail'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
  actionmailer (4.0.0) lib/action_mailer/base.rb:454:in `deliver_mail'
  mail (2.5.4) lib/mail/message.rb:232:in `deliver'
  devise (3.2.4) lib/devise/models/authenticatable.rb:173:in `send_devise_notification'
  devise (3.2.4) lib/devise/models/confirmable.rb:102:in `send_confirmation_instructions'
  devise (3.2.4) lib/devise/models/confirmable.rb:117:in `block in resend_confirmation_instructions'
  devise (3.2.4) lib/devise/models/confirmable.rb:211:in `pending_any_confirmation'
  devise (3.2.4) lib/devise/models/confirmable.rb:116:in `resend_confirmation_instructions'
  devise (3.2.4) lib/devise/models/confirmable.rb:265:in `send_confirmation_instructions'
  devise (3.2.4) app/controllers/devise/confirmations_controller.rb:9:in `create'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:189:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:423:in `_run__3176473197347058618__process_action__callbacks'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:245:in `process_action'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:44:in `process'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:231:in `block in action'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:48:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:44:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in `block in call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `each'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:655:in `call'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:35:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:241:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:486:in `call'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:626:in `call'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/migration.rb:369:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:373:in `_run__455108311755261639__call__callbacks'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:64:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:25:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `tagged'
  railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
  railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
  railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'


  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (0.9ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (1.1ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (0.9ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (16.0ms)
```

**development.rb :**

```
Yoshirt::Application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # In the development environment your application's code is reloaded on
  # every request. This slows down response time but is perfect for development
  # since you don't have to restart the web server when you make code changes.
  config.cache_classes = false

  # Do not eager load code on boot.
  config.eager_load = false

  # Show full error reports and disable caching.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

  # Don't care if the mailer can't send.
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Print deprecation notices to the Rails logger.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log

  # Raise an error on page load if there are pending migrations
  config.active_record.migration_error = :page_load

  # Debug mode disables concatenation and preprocessing of assets.
  # This option may cause significant delays in view rendering with a large
  # number of complex assets.
  config.assets.debug = true

  # Defining default url options for devise
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost', port: 3000 }

  # Change to true to allow email to be sent during development
  # http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21610815/how-to-config-devise-gem-to-send-email-to-the-resource
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true

  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    address: "smtp.gmail.com",
    port: 587,
    domain: "mail.google.com",####important
    authentication: "plain",
    enable_starttls_auto: true,
    user_name: ENV["GMAIL_USERNAME"],
    password: ENV["GMAIL_PASSWORD"]
  }

end
```

Comment: If you have `2-step authentication setup` on you gmail account then you cannot use the original password here. In that case you would have to generate an application specific password and use that in your `config.action_mailer.smtp_settings`

Comment: @KirtiThorat Thanks for that info as I might need it later on down the line, but I'm not using a 2-step authentication on my gmail account.

Comment: Let's discuss this on chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48530/ror

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As per the chat session with OP, `GMAIL_USERNAME` and `GMAIL_PASSWORD` were not being picked up from `.env` which was resulting in this error.

Hardcoding the `user_name` and `password` in `development.rb` works perfectly.

I would highly recommend you to go for [`figaro`](https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro) gem which is an excellent way to securely configure Rails applications.

Also, read this excellent article by *Daniel Kehoe and Taylor Mock* on **[Rails Environment Variables](http://railsapps.github.io/rails-environment-variables.html)**. You would also get an idea on how to use figaro gem in your application.

Comment: You have a typo. Please change "fiagaro" to "figaro". I tried to edit but it did not get submit as the change was less than 6 chars

Answer (score 2):

You can change security of Gmail and activate authorization for the less safe apps in [Google's settings here](https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @eirikir: That's not a documentation page; that's the actual place you make the settings change, and the provided information is pretty much all you really need. Considering it a link-only answer is therefore gravely in error.

Answer (score 0):

You followed [this, or something like it](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#action-mailer-configuration-for-gmail), it looks like your configuration is fine.

So either your username/password is wrong, or maybe you didn't restart the server after you made those configuration changes?  Is there nothing more to that error message?

Comment: thanks for looking this... the username and password are correct as it seems to be working fine on my remote project.

Comment: I've updated my Rails Server logs to show the entirety of what's happening after I send an email confirmation... there's a repeating line that reads something like **'block in deliver'** or **'block in action'** I'm not really sure what this means right now.

Comment: You say it's working fine on your remote project, is this the same project?  It's just not working locally in development mode?

Comment: To anyone still having these problems - try restarting your server after editing the configs, just did that and finally got things working!

Answer (score 0):

For people who find this post and none of the above worked, FYI the development.rb where the mail settings are located loads pretty early in the initialization process for rails.

My fix:

I created a environment_variables.yml in the config directory and added my variables there. I also added this tidbit of code to the application.rb because the application.rb loads before the development.rb.

```
config.before_configuration do
        env_file = Rails.root.join("config", 'environment_variables.yml').to_s
        if File.exists?(env_file)
          YAML.load_file(env_file)[Rails.env].each do |key, value|
            ENV[key.to_s] = value
          end # end YAML.load_file
        end # end if File.exists?
    end # end config.before_configuration
```